# Show that if $\lim_{\textbf{h}\to \textbf{0}}{T(\textbf{h})}=0$, then $\lim_{t\to 0}{T(t\textbf{v})}=0$ for some fixed $\textbf{v}$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, vectors

I don't even know where to start with this. What exactly is the question? There is no context for this, by the way, that's all the question is.

Am I meant to state that $\textbf{h}=t\textbf{v}$ for some $t$? And then because of that, $\textbf{h}\to \textbf{0}$ is the same as $t\to 0$ for $t\textbf{v}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $\mathbf{h\to0}$ is meant to be a statement that the limit is true *from all directions*. The second limit is a limit only from *one* direction.

Comment: First, why only one direction? Is it not two directions, since $t$ can be positive or negative?

And, I still don't understand how I'm meant to show what the question is asking.

Comment: Sure, the point is it's only along one straight line, whereas the first limit is along all possible paths.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, but how do I show what the question is asking? Or, more specifically, how do I express formally that $t\to 0$ is the same $\textbf{h}\to\textbf{0}$, but along a straight line? Or do I just state what you stated and that's enough?

Comment: Write out the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition for each statement, and see why the second follows from the first. Such questions are really more of a test of whether you understood the definitions.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that then. Thank you.

Comment: @Trisztan Exactly what peek-a-boo said. Your question has sufficient context for us to be allowed to answer, but giving an answer at this point would nullify the value of the exercise. You are trying to show that $\lim_{t \to 0} T(t\mathbf{v}) = 0$. Write out what it means, with $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$. Start your proof by saying "Suppose $\varepsilon > 0$...". What does $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to 0}T(\mathbf{h})$ guarantee you?

Comment: @Theo Bendit It guarantees you have $\delta>|\textbf{h}-\textbf{0}|>0$, or that $\delta>\sqrt{(h_1-0)^2+\cdots+(h_n-0)^2}>0$, such that $|T(\textbf{h})|<\varepsilon$. Although I'm still not sure how this implies that you have $\delta>|t-0|>0$ such that $|T(t\textbf{v})|<\varepsilon$ for the second limit.

Comment: @Trisztan It gives you a $\delta$ with this property. But, this $\delta$ may not be the $\delta$ we are interested in, with reference to $\lim_{t \to 0} T(t\mathbf{v}) = 0$. So, we should call it $\delta'$, or something like that. Now, think about this: how small does $|t|$ have to be to ensure that $|t\mathbf{v}| < \delta'$? You may want to consider the $\mathbf{v} = 0$ case separately.

Comment: @TheoBendit Assuming that $\delta=\delta'$, small enough such that $t\textbf{v}\leq\textbf{h}$? I'm sorry, I really don't know, and unfortunately I couldn't find similar questions or examples in the textbook I'm using.

Comment: This is one of those cases where a picture will point you in the right direction. Draw a circle about the origin, imagine $\vec h$ is *any* vector  from the origin with endpoint on the circle. What does the first definition imply? Now, *fix* a vector $\vec h$ on the circle, multiply it by the scalar $t$ and let $t$ approach zero. Observe that the first condition certainly implies the second, geometrically at least. Now translate this into an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: @Matematleta It implies that the length of each such vector $\textbf{h}$, which is the radius of the circle, is less than $\delta$. And yes, this clearly implies, at least intuitively, that an expression $t\textbf{h}$ will also approach $0$ as $t\to 0$. The problem is I don't know how to express this using $\varepsilon-\delta$. But I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you gave it a go. Here's how I'd do it.

First, I want to say, we are assuming $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$. Without this assumption, the result need not be true! The need for this assumption will become apparent in the argument, and I'll give an example of the conclusion breaking down when $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$ at the end.

Suppose $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}} T(\mathbf{h}) = 0$, there exists some $\delta' > 0$ such that
$$0 < |\mathbf{h} - \mathbf{0}| < \delta' \implies |T(\mathbf{h}) - 0| < \varepsilon. \tag{$\star$}$$
Informally, we can make $T(\mathbf{h})$ as small as we like by making $\mathbf{h}$ sufficiently small. We have some control over $\mathbf{h}$; there's nothing to say it can't take the form $t \mathbf{v}$. So long as we make $t \mathbf{v}$ sufficiently small (i.e. so long as we force $0 < |t \mathbf{v}| < \delta'$), then the conclusion $|T(t\mathbf{v})| < \varepsilon$ will still hold.

We are interested in finding $\delta > 0$ such that
$$0 < |t - 0| < \delta \implies |T(t\mathbf{v}) - 0| < \varepsilon.$$
Note that the conclusion here, $|T(t\mathbf{v}) - 0| < \varepsilon$, is the same as $|T(\mathbf{h}) - 0| < \varepsilon$, if we choose $\mathbf{h} = t\mathbf{v}$. What we are aiming for is something like this:
$$0 < |t - 0| < \delta \implies 0 < |t\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{0}| < \delta' \color{red}\implies |T(t\mathbf{v}) - 0| < \varepsilon,$$
where the red $\color{red}\implies$ is given by specifying $(\star)$ to $\mathbf{h}$ of the form $t\mathbf{v}$. So, we just need to choose $\delta$ to satisfy the other implication:
$$0 < |t - 0| < \delta \implies 0 < |t\mathbf{v} - \mathbf{0}| < \delta'.$$
To do this, don't use the definition of the norm. Use the fact that
$$|t\mathbf{v}| = |t| |\mathbf{v}|.$$
If we choose $\delta = \delta' / |\mathbf{v}|$ (note $\mathbf{v} \neq \mathbf{0}$, so $|\mathbf{v}| \neq 0$), then
\begin{align*}
0 < |t| < \delta &\implies 0 < |t| < \frac{\delta'}{|\mathbf{v}|} \\
&\implies 0 < |t||\mathbf{v}| < \delta' \\
&\implies 0 < |t\mathbf{v}| < \delta',
\end{align*}
as required. Then, the red $\color{red}\implies$ holds by our construction of $\delta'$, and the argument is complete: we started with arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$, and constructed $\delta > 0$ such that
$$0 < |t - 0| < \delta \implies |T(t\mathbf{v}) - 0| < \varepsilon.$$

---

If $\mathbf{v} = \mathbf{0}$, then the above result doesn't hold. It means that $T(t\mathbf{v})$ is a constant, and is equal to $T(\mathbf{0})$. If this is $0$, then we're fine and the result holds. But, simply because $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}T(\mathbf{h}) = 0$, does not mean that $T$ is continuous there! It could be that $T(\mathbf{0})$ is some non-zero number (or vector, more generally). In this case, $\lim_{t \to 0} T(t\mathbf{v})$ will be this non-zero constant, even though $\lim_{\mathbf{h} \to \mathbf{0}}T(\mathbf{h}) = 0$.

As a specific example, consider $T : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ defined by:
$$T(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 1 & \text{if } x = 0. \end{cases}$$

Comment: I... I didn't realise you could split $|t\textbf{v}|$ into $|t||\textbf{v}|$. I just did the expansion and now see that you can. Thank you very much, it makes perfect sense now.